# how to attach scanner in flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash

I want to attach scanner to a flex application and read the image using scanner.Does anyone know how to attach scanner to a flex application?.

Answer (score 1):

if you're building an AIR application with a native installer, you can incorporate a serial proxy ([here's a list](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/SerialNet)) and use the new File and NativeProcess APIs to (probably) communicate with a scanner.

Mike Chambers details how to accomplish [serial communication with an Arduino on his blog](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2010/08/04/getting-started-with-flash-and-arduino/).

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. Flash Player only permits access to **camera and microphone**.

See: [Your privacy and Adobe Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/privacy.html)